# Index number in descending order

Tags: angular, angular-material-5

My table contains indexing number and when i add a new row its should show me in 2,1,0 i need current value in the top index number 2.As per my code its working 0,1,2.
But i need it in 2,1,0.

This is my html file
`

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource"  *ngFor="let field of fieldArray | reverse; let i = index " [attr.data-index]="i" >                 
<ng-container matColumnDef="SrNo">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >                 
<div>{{i}}</div>
</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Here is my pipe code

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'reverse',
  pure: false
})
export class ReversePipe implements PipeTransform {

transform (values) {
    return values.reverse();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you reverse the order of your dataSource or fieldArray in your component ts file?

Comment: datasource would reverse the value but i need index to be reversed

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you just want the index to be reversed, not the items, instead of using the `reverse` and displaying the `i` directly, you could do :

```
[attr.data-index]="fieldArray.length - i"
```

and

```
<div>{{fieldArray.length - i}}</div>
```

That way you'll get ...,2,1,0 instead of 0,1,2...

Comment: ,Ohh great its working thank you
Since i have added it in datasource even header is repeating along with row so how can i avoid header displaying multiple times with row.
I tried adding ngFor in separate div but in that case row is not adding.so were will i add ngFor so that header should not repeat

Answer (score 0):

You can sort directly the array "fieldArray" you dont need to use a pipe.

```
fieldArray.sort((a, b) => a < b? 1 : 0);
```